# How to Perform Text to Column in R Similar Like Excel using function cSplit()

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to find a way to perform the text to column function in R which has a delimiter as this sign "~" while also using the function `cSplit`.

Attached is the data frame which I am dealing with `Book1`.

```
Book1 <- structure(list(V1 = "\"~\\500\"~\\Neuron\"~\\Splits\"~\\California\"~\\Orange\"~\\Men\"~\\SKU\"~\\6704Coffee\"~\\Tea\"~\\Espresso", 
        V2 = "Solution"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

The code I have written is given below:

```
library(writexl)
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)
Book1 <- read_excel("C:/Users/X/x- x/Desktop/Book1.xlsx")
cSplit(Book1, splitCols = "V1",sep = "~",direction = "wide",verbose = FALSE)
```

Please let me know what I am done wrong here and what would be a better way to write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `cSplit` then you need to remove the `verbose` argument since this is not a function argument, see `?cSplit`:

```r
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(Book1, splitCols = "V1",sep = "~")
```

You can also pass a regular expression:

```r
cSplit(Book1, "V1", "[^[:alnum:]]+", fixed = F)
#          V2 V1_01 V1_02  V1_03  V1_04      V1_05  V1_06 V1_07 V1_08      V1_09 V1_10    V1_11
# 1: Solution    NA   500 Neuron Splits California Orange   Men   SKU 6704Coffee   Tea Espresso
```

Note: you will get a  warning message since `cSplit` uses `type.convert` which attempts to convert columns to their appropriate type (e.g. 500 as numeric, instead of "500" as character).

---

Using some `tidyverse` packages:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
separate_wider_delim(Book1, V1, delim = regex("[^[:alnum:]]+"), names = paste0("x", 1:11))
```

Or

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

Book1 |> 
  mutate(x = map(str_extract_all(V1, "[:alnum:]+"), ~ set_names(.x, paste0('x', seq_along(.x))))) |>
  unnest_wider(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read.delim`:

```
> data.frame(read.delim(text  = Book1$V1, sep = "~", header = FALSE), Book1$V2)
      V1                V2                    V3          V4                 V5         V6 Book1.V2
1 ~\\500 \\Neuron~\\Splits \\California~\\Orange \\Men~\\SKU \\6704Coffee~\\Tea \\Espresso Solution
```

A cleaner version:

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(read.delim(text  = Book1$V1, sep = "~", header = FALSE), Book1$V2) %>% 
  mutate_all(~str_extract(., pattern =  "\\w+"))

   V1     V2         V3  V4         V5       V6 Book1.V2
1 500 Neuron California Men 6704Coffee Espresso Solution
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any data in your columns, they just have column names, correct?

The following code below works for me:

```
# Your dataset
Book1 <- structure(list(V1 = "\"~\\500\"~\\Neuron\"~\\Splits\"~\\California\"~\\Orange\"~\\Men\"~\\SKU\"~\\6704Coffee\"~\\Tea\"~\\Espresso",
                        V2 = "Solution"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))

# Split the text in column V1 based on the "~\\" delimiter
Book1_split <- strsplit(as.character(Book1$V1), "~\\", fixed = TRUE)

# Convert the list of vectors into a data frame
Book1_result <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(Book1_split), nrow = length(Book1_split), byrow = TRUE))

# Rename the columns based on the original column names
colnames(Book1_result) <- paste0("V", seq_len(ncol(Book1_result)))

# Combine the result with the original dataset
result <- cbind(Book1, Book1_result)

# Print the result
print(result)
```

Lasty: This code will split the text in column V1 based on the "~" delimiter and create new columns accordingly. The resulting data frame `View(result)` will include the original columns and the newly created columns from the split operation.